# Python checking if sentence is in a sentence

Tags: python, string

I have a file containing a list of words, in such a format:

WordCorpus.txt

```
Mdbg
Homomorphism
Nhibernate Search
Userscripts
Python Social Auth
Quadratic Equation
```

Basically they are line separated.
This is the first line of text1:

This is my code:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    text = myfile.read()
final = []
text1 = text.title()
print "Quadratic Equation" in text1

with open('WordCorpus.txt','r') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        if line in text1:
            final.append(line)
print len(final)
```

The output I get is

True

0

If I get true that means text1 has "Quadratic Equation" and my file also has it, in this case why is line not appended in final?

Comment: We can't definitively debug this without the *full* example that elicits the problem.  You haven't included the other input file.

Comment: Because you are including the `\n` newline separator. The string `"Quadratic Equation\n"` does not appear in your text.

Comment: `line = line.strip()` will remove all leading and trailing whitespace, including a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is due to not `strip`ping the input.  In your lower loops, the text you search fro will be "Quadratic Equation\n", which (apparently) does not appear in `text.txt`.